# Unity PlayerPrefs are not working when the game is build for Windows

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For my game I use PlayerPrefs to store the overall player score and the score for every level. In editor, there were no issue with creating, updating and deleting PlayerPrefs. But when I build the game, issues started to show up.

The PlayerPrefs would be created and updated as usual, but the deletion was broken.

This is the code that is used in a button to reset the score

```
public void ResetProgress()
{
    
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Application.persistentDataPath))
    {
        File.Delete(file);
    }
    PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
    
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    
}
```

In editor, this button will delete the PlayerPrefs from the registry(I used regedit and an addon from the asset store to make sure of that). But when build, the registries will simply stay and the scene that shows the values provided by those PlayerPrefs will not change.

This is the code for saving data

```
string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + levelName + ".dat";

//Check if there is any save file to begin with
if(File.Exists(path))
{
    File.AppendAllText(path, playerSolution + Environment.NewLine);
    string[] playerValues = PlayerPrefs.GetString(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name).Split('-').ToArray();
    PlayerPrefs.SetString(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name, $"{int.Parse(playerValues[0]) + 1}-{playerTime}");
}
else
{
    File.WriteAllText(path, playerSolution + Environment.NewLine);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name, $"1-{playerTime}");
}

if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("AllPlayerScore"))
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("AllPlayerScore", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("AllPlayerScore") + 1);
}
else
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("AllPlayerScore", 1);
}
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

And yes, I am aware that when you build a game, the registry directory will change.
I've also tried to delete the registries to see if somehow my values are being cached, but no. Everything resets as expected.

Some final notes:

- The files that I create and delete are not connected to scores
- The logic from the button IS being called, because the files are being deleted
- The project is build in LTS version 2020.3.30f1

UPDATE 1: I have no clue why, but the problem was fixed in the button logic when I moved the PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll() to be executed before the file removal.
I will keep the post open, so that someone far more knowledgeable can explain the issue.

Comment: In general the thing that deletes the PlayerPrefs from the registry is `PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();` - your deletion of the `persistentDataPath` files has nothing to do with it

Comment: @derHugo as I just said in the first updated , somehow by moving the DeleteAll() method before the file deletion made it work.

Comment: sounds like in your build you get a FileIO exception and therefore it never reaches the PlayerPrefs line ;)

Comment: @derHugo Nice, I had the same thought :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to call this a partial answer. In some cases when I reproduce this problem, the method is exiting early due to an exception caused by a file refusing to be deleted which skips the `PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll(); PlayerPrefs.Save();` calls.

Surrounding the call in a try/catch block fixes this particular cause.

```
public void ResetProgress()
{  
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Application.persistentDataPath))
    {
        try 
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
        catch {}
    }

    PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

Comment: It's not partial, it is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a hunch, but I would like you to be aware of the following, which is to long for a comment:

The path separation character differs between Windows `\` and Unix `/` like systems. This might lead to incorrect paths when you do cross-platform development and hence, failing to load data.

To overcome this you should use `Path.PathSeparator` or `Path.` static functions whenever possible.

So:

```
string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + levelName + ".dat";
```

would become:

```
string path = Application.persistentDataPath + 
              Path.PathSeparator + levelName + ".dat";
```

Do note you might have the same issue with the `Application.persistentDataPath` variable.

Note: as derHugo mentioned, a better option is to use `Path.Combine` :

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, levelName + ".dat");
```

More info, see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-6.0

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.pathseparator?view=net-6.0

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although it doesn't exactly fix the problem, it's still good to know.

Comment: The way you currently concatenate the path will definitely cause issues on some windows systems,keep that in mind.

Comment: Just use `Path.Combine` which already uses the correct path separator and is more efficient then multiple string concatenations

Comment: Good point, Ill add it...